# How to make directions in angular-google-maps

Tags: angular-google-maps

I am using [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) module but I am not able to make direction from point to point on map e.g. like [here](https://github.com/jbdemonte/angular-google-maps-native/blob/master/examples/directions.html). I have found nothing about this in documentation or even in examples.

Is anybody here who know how to do it?